# How do you create multi colored pins in a map?

Tags: iphone, colors, annotations, maps, android-mapview

My map needs to display RED pins for "Venues", and BLUE pins for "Parking Lots" near and around them.

The problem is that both pins show up in the same color.

The code is below:

My pinAnnotation class looks like this:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface mapPinAnnotation : NSObject  <MKAnnotation>  {    
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *pinType; // this string will be set to either "Venue" or "Parking"
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title, *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pinType;


@end
```

This is the implementation:

```
#import "mapPinAnnotation.h"

@implementation mapPinAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize pinType;
@synthesize title, subtitle;

-(id) initWithCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
    coordinate = c;
    return self;
}    

@end
```

Here is the method setting the pins - note that I use a "tempPin" variable - declared globally - so I can then pass that pin into the "viewForAnnotation" method - but I think this is where the problem is:

```
-(void) dropThePin {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;        

    if(pinAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
        [pinAnnotation release];
        pinAnnotation = nil;
    }

    // Create (alloc/init) a Pin, set its Title & Subtitle, and add/place it:
    pinAnnotation = [[mapPinAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    pinAnnotation.pinType = @"VENUE";

    tempPin = pinAnnotation;

    [pinAnnotation setTitle: @"Some Stadium"];
    [pinAnnotation setSubtitle: @"123 Main St."];

    [mapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];


    // Set-Up of 2nd. Pin:
    location.latitude = 12.34567;
    location.longitude = -23.45678;

    pinAnnotation.pinType = @"PARKING";
    if(parkingLotPin != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:parkingLotPin];
        [parkingLotPin release];
        parkingLotPin = nil;
    }

    // Create (alloc/init) a Pin, set its Title & Subtitle, and add/place it:
    parkingLotPin = [[mapPinAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];

    tempPin = pinAnnotation;
    [parkingLotPin setTitle: @"Another Venue"];
    [parkingLotPin setSubtitle: @"789 S. Broad Street"];

    [mapView addAnnotation:parkingLotPin];
    [parkingLotPin release];

}
```

Finally, here is the "viewForAnnotation" method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *thePin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    if (tempPin.pinType == @"VENUE") {
        thePin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        NSLog(@"pin-type = %@", tempPin.pinType);
    } else {
        thePin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        NSLog(@"pin-type = %@", tempPin.pinType);
    }

    thePin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    thePin.canShowCallout = YES;
    thePin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return thePin;
}
```

The problem is that both pins show up with the same color.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you want to use `isEqualToString:` instead of `==` when you are comparing the `.pinType`.

Comment: Tried it (isEqualToString) - doesn't work :-(

Comment: You have to compare the strings via the method `isEqualToString` and not `==`, as the first one actually compares the string, and the second doesn't. There may be other issues with your code, but that is for sure one of them. Also, you should release your first pin annotation after you add it, and then allocate a new one immediately afterwards before setting anything. It seems as though you are setting your `.pinType = @"PARKING"` *BEFORE* you are allocating the new pin.

Comment: 'if (tempPin.pinType == @"VENUE")'.  You are using tempPin in the if statement.  This is set outside the viewForAnnotation function.  When the mapview finally goes to get all the views it's going to use the same tempPin for all of them, so you'll get one color.

Comment: @MSgmabel - yes, I tried the isEqualToString bit - its really not the issue. You can use == or isEqualToString and its the same result. (I tested it with NSLogs both ways- same result.)  I also just tried releasing the pin as you suggested before allocating the new pin - that also didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if (tempPin.pinType == @"VENUE") {
```

to:

```
if ([((mapPinAnnotation*)annotation).pinType isEqualToString:@"VENUE"]) {
```

Comment: Essentially correct though it should be `(mapPinAnnotation *)`.  @sirab333, the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method gives you a reference to the annotation it needs the view for--you have to use that reference.  You can't reliably use an ivar to tell which annotation the map view is calling the method for.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, and the more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([tempPin.pinType isEqualToStirng:@"VENUE"]) {
    thePin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    NSLog(@"pin-type = %@", tempPin.pinType);
} else {
    thePin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    NSLog(@"pin-type = %@", tempPin.pinType);
}
```

[Also look at this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW33)

Comment: @Joe - you are correct, and that's exactly the problem - which I think I mentioned in my original posting.  So the question remains: how do you SOLVE this? :-) How do you modify the 'viewForAnnotation' method so it displays the right color for each pin?